# String.xml with too many items is too slow

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

After adding `<item>170,000</items>` to `string.xml`. It becomes so slow in building workspace, I increase my heap space and jvm memory, but is still slow I had to wait 4 hours after every edit to save on eclipse before i think of running the program.

Any solution please? (Am using gnome 3.0 on ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: xml files are not designed to have so much data

Comment: An XML file is not a database.

Comment: ye 170,000 strings. I want the app to be non internet. if not i will use online database to store those strings.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having 170,000 nodes in an XML document. It's completely normal. It's the way it's being done that's wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKay it makes eclipsce so slow for days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of placing strings in `string.xml`, why don't you try placing a file inside `/res/raw` and when the app starts for the first time you insert it into a db?

Comment: Or, better yet, use [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) and package the a database with the app.

Comment: i use a file reader.. its even worst. i have use sql on Java but not on android, how do i use it on android do i have to download an sql software to do it. Is there like a free server out there where i can upload my file to and initiate it from the android app.

Comment: @Immanuel.I.George: You don't need a sql software to do it. Android comes with `SQLite`.

Comment: @Macarse ok i downloaded an Sql lite DB browser and imported csv file of 170,000 words to it that took two days to be exact. So now i copied it to my asset folder. do u knw the kind of code i will use to call those records. Plus if someone is using my app or installing my app is d database already packaged with the apk file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you are doing. How are you building this XML file? Perhaps you are using Java string concatenation? That will certainly be extremely slow. I would do it using something like an XMLStreamWriter. But you need to describe your scenario in more detail, for example I don't see where Eclipse comes into it.

Comment: Actually Eclipse comes into it. i have 170,000 words to be use as a reference or compared with user input if its correct it display correct or whatever, is more complicated than that. Ok, my biggest problem its finding a convenient way in storing this words , first i use file reader, but its not even seeing it. i used file reader on Java and it was easy just copy the file to the folder of the project and just call the name, it was easy. But on android I don't know the exact place place to copy file.txt. I was not also sure the .txt file will be packaged with .apk file.

Comment: SO my option was to use <items></item>on string.xml but it became so slow. it took hours to build. Now am left with sql lite which am not even sure it will be packaged with .apk. Please help me